# How does DNS resolving and caching work on Ubuntu?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I'm trying to understand more about DNS resolving and caching on Ubuntu 16.04. What does a standard install of Ubuntu uses (systemd, dnsmasq)? what configuration files are used? What processes are involved (NetworkManager, dhcp)? This might be a more general linux question, but browsing through this forum made me rather confused.

Is there any (extended) **documentation** on this topic? Is there any information on the choices made for Ubuntu?

Comment: How much do you know about networking in general? I can go as deep as you like but I don't want to be talking about TCP/IP if I can avoid it.

Comment: @mr_woggle There is no extended documentation for this, and the 'choices' made are not publicly documented, to my knowledge.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I think they want specifics related to Ubuntu and the 'decisions' related in the choices of network management systems and DNS caching done for Ubuntu by the development teams, rather than an overview of how DNS Resolving/Caching works in general.

Comment: I understand DNS resolving and caching. It's just rather confusing to me what Ubuntu does. For example /etc/resolv.conf is apparently used by multiple processes (dnsmasq, avahi and what not). I can figure out what each process does on its own, but I'm kinda lost beyond. I'm just looking for some reference on this topic